# Correctly configure httpd.conf for django site

Tags: django, apache, wamp, windows-10, mod-wsgi

So I'm trying to deploy my django project using `apache 2.2` and `mod_wsgi`. I've gotten to the point of configuring my `httpd.conf` file for `apache` but think I might be doing something wrong since I keep getting `"403: You don't have permission to access / on this server."` when trying to access my site.[image]

This is what my project structure looks like:

```
"C:\wamp2.2\ums" 
myapp/
    pm_app/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    ums/
        static/..
        templates/..
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        views.py
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
```

`pm_app` contains the `wsgi.py` file and ums is the folder with the site

wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('C:/wamp2.2/ums')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pm_app.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

httpd.conf:

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp2.2/ums"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wamp2.2/ums/pm_app"

<Directory "C:/wamp2.2/ums/ums">
<Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Did I get my pathing wrong, or am I missing something. Am I also accessing the site correctly via `localhost` or should it be `localhost/ums`?

Comment: I know that is not the answer you are looking for, but I think you would do yourself a favor and use nginx + gunicorn... found this less hassle myself...

Comment: isn't that more so for unix than windows? at least the gunicorn

Comment: oops, you are right, havent thought about that, gunicorn is not windows compatible, sorry about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after scratching my head I figured I'd look at the apache error logs which were far more helpful. Seems my `Directory` and `Files` tags had the wrong values.

This is what works for me:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wamp2.2/ums/pm_app/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp2.2/ums/env/Lib/site-packages";"C:/wamp2.2/ums/pm_app"

<Directory "C:/wamp2.2/ums/pm_app">
    <Files "wsgi.py">
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```